# Fast unicode input in Emacs with US layout

Tags: unicode, emacs, keyboard

I would like to have a quick way to input unicode characters with multicharacter sequences. For example to input `ä` I would type `\a`. Searching for this, I found [agda-input](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Docs.UnicodeInput).

While I could adapt the `agda-input` for my use, I don't really need the whole emacs mode for my purpose. So I was wondering if such thing already exists.

It is probably also not that difficult to code such input mode. I would appriciate if someone suggested on how to do that.

Comment: agda-input is an input method. You can find others with `M-x set-input-method` and tab completion. Perhaps the `TeX` input method does what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @legoscia mentioned, you can use the TeX input method for such things, which is probably more general than agda-input (which seems to be specific for a programming language) and is also built in.

```
(setq default-input-method "TeX")
```

Then switch to the input method with `C-\` or `M-x toggle-input-method`.  You can then type "ä" with `\"a`.  The minibuffer has hints when you type `\`.

There are other input methods (`M-x list-input-methods`), but TeX is a good one if you're not concerned with a specific language, or if you know LaTeX.

Comment: Do you know how to customize/remove sequences? It says something [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TeXInputMethod), but it's not very clear. Is there any documentation on TeX input mode?